# Why are stimuli offset when psychopy code is run on mac?

Tags: python, macos, ubuntu, window, psychopy

Window parameters that work on a PC running Ubuntu 16.04 result in stimuli that are left-offset on a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015) running High Sierra 10.13.2. I believe that I’m using the same version of Psychopy (installed via Conda, so without the standalone package/Builder) and I’m using Pyglet 1.3.0. Both operating systems are using a virtual environment that uses Python 2.7.

I’ve tested this using several different task scripts that were previously functional on Ubuntu and this problem seems to be independent of the retina pixel to logical pixel conversion problem (where there are 2 retina pixels for every logical pixel).

I’m new to Psychopy, so there may be some obvious solution that I’m missing – if so, I really appreciate your help!

Window code:

```
window = visual.Window(size=[1440,900],pos = [0,0], monitor='testMonitor', color = [-1,-1,-1],
       colorSpace = 'rgb', blendMode = 'avg', useFBO = False, allowGUI =
       False,fullscr=False, winType='pyglet',units='cm')
```

[An example of the problem (fractals should be at center of screen)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6cPL.png)

Comment: By not showing us how you specify the position of the stimuli, you haven't made it possible to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

The question was duplicated on the PsychoPy forum and was answered there:
https://discourse.psychopy.org/t/stimuli-on-mac-retina-display-are-in-bottom-left-corner/3739/3